# LibGDX: Ray collision with 3d model?

Tags: 3d, libgdx, collision, raytracing

How would I go about detecting whether or not a ray sent from where the user touches the screen

`Ray ray = cam.getPickRay(touchX, touchY)` where cam is a perspective camera

intersects with a polygonal model.
My current method of clicking on cubes doesn't work in certain cases shown here: http://screencloud.net/v/7z86 as it isnt checking for the model's unique polygon

im using `shape = loader.loadModel(Gdx.files.internal(model));` to declare my shapes and
`shapeInst = new ModelInstance(shape);` to declare my ModelInstance

As you can see in the picture above my models are not perfect squares but rather unique polygons.

TL;DR what is the correct method of ray tracing and getting intersection detection on 3d models

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988852/raycasting-in-libgdx-3d/24989069#24989069 (if you are using bullet)

Comment: im not but ill look into it